# Unable to Install Quartz.Net from Nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget, quartz.net

I am trying to install Quartz.net in an application and getting following error

**PM> Install-Package Quartz -Version 3.0.2**

```
Installing 'Quartz 3.0.2'.

Successfully installed 'Quartz 3.0.2'.

Adding 'Quartz 3.0.2' to Service.

Uninstalling 'Quartz 3.0.2'.

Successfully uninstalled 'Quartz 3.0.2'.

Install failed. Rolling back...
```

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Quartz 3.0.2'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author. At line:1
>   char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  Quartz -Version 3.0.2
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of Quartz.NET requires .NET 4.5.2.
Your project uses .NET 4.5.1.

Quartz.NET 2.6.1 is the most recent version that I'm seeing that might for you.
It doesn't like a .NET version requirement.
Hopefully that means that it works with 4.5.1.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz/2.6.1

Comment: It worked thanks, I got confused between versions I thought I was using 4.5.2 but I wasn't my bad.

Answer (score 0):

The Quartz 3.0.2 [change log](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/changelog.md) states that after updating the minimum requirements to .NET 4.6 it was brought down again to .NET 4.5.2, so you might as well try changing your project target to it.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you're trying to install Quartz to a .net 4.5 project but it isn't compatible with that framework. The dependencies list for [Quartz 3.0.2 on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz/) state it requires .net 4.5.2 or .net standard 2.0

You could try using an older version (before 3.0.0 as this seems to be when it was updated for .net 4.5.2/netstandard2.0) eg `Install-Package Quartz -Version 2.6.1` or updating the framework for your project to be .net 4.5.2 or higher. In visual studio you can update your target framework by right clicking the project, selecting `properties`, and changing the `Target Framework:` dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is actually telling you whats going on

> You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework

If you go to the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz/) page you will see the dependencies

**.NETFramework 4.5.2**

or

**.NETStandard 2.0**

```
Microsoft.CSharp (>= 4.4.0)
System.Collections.NonGeneric (>= 4.3.0)
System.Collections.Specialized (>= 4.3.0)
System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter (>= 4.3.0)
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager (>= 4.4.0)
System.Data.Common (>= 4.3.0)
System.Data.SqlClient (>= 4.4.0)
System.Net.NameResolution (>= 4.3.0)
System.Reflection.TypeExtensions (>= 4.4.0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml (>= 4.3.0)
System.Threading.Thread (>= 4.3.0)
System.Xml.XmlSerializer (>= 4.3.0)
```

You need to upgrade your frame work to at least `4.5.2`